# Memory management with parentheses, braces and nothing

Tags: c++, memory

I have the following C++ program which I compile with clang++-5.0 and run on Ubuntu:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

constexpr int SIZE=125*1000*1024; // 125000 KB

class Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

class Points {
    Point pointsarray[SIZE];
};

int main() {
    cout << "Before new" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));

    auto p = new Points{};  

    cout << "After new" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5));
}
```

While the program runs, I look at the free memory using:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree
```

I see that, as expected, the statement "p = new Points{};" takes about 1,000,000 KB.

The same happens when I change this statement to "p = new Points();".

However, when I change it to "p = new Points;", the memory consumption becomes zero - the free memory before and after the statement is the same!

Question 1: why does the statement without parens take no memory?

Question 2: what is the difference, with regard to memory, between using parens vs braces?

Comment: If you don't initialise the instance then the VM system is free to allocate it lazily (i.e. "on demand").

Comment: @PaulR what is VM? I thought only Java has VM...

Comment: VM here stands for "virtual memory", not "virtual machine".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some operating systems don't actually give you memory until you write to it.

`{}` and `()` initialize your structs with zeroes, while lack of them leaves those structs uninitialized.
This behaviour is unique to implicitly-generated and `=default`ed default constructors, and can't be replicated with user-defined default constructors.

Reference: [cppreference/**value_initialization**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

> ... **if `T` is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted** (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), **the object is zero-initialized** and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor;

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The latter notation causes Points to be uninitialised. Allocating uninitialised memory is very cheap because it is done *lazily*. For all practical purposes, no real allocation takes place until the allocated memory is accessed.

You can verify this by running over your array after operator new returns and assigning some values to the points. Then memory consumption will suddenly become normal again.

All of this is implementation-specific of course but all "big" modern operating systems work this way.